# How to improve this algorithm for correcting the position of decimal for a stream of numbers

Tags: c#

How can I improve the below algorithm for the following problem?

1. A stream of numbers is received.
2. At some point in the stream, numbers begin arriving which have the decimal point in the wrong place
3. After a period of time the error disappears and correct values enter the stream.

How can I correct the numbers with the decimal point in the wrong place?

Note that the incorrect numbers are NOT out by exactly a multiple of ten. Here are example streams:

It can be assumed that numbers will always be greater than zero and that they differ by less than 50% from one value to the next.

```
11.111
11.112
11.113
1111.4 // wrong
1111.5 // wrong
11.116
11.117


0.000011111
0.000011112
0.000011113
111.14       // wrong
111.15       // wrong
0.000011116
0.000011117


0.000011111
0.000011112
0.000011113
0.0011114   // wrong
0.0011115   // wrong
0.000011116
0.000011117
```

Here's the code I would like to improve:

```
    static double lastValue = -1;
    static void OnValue(double value) {
        if (value <= 0)
            return;
        if (lastValue != -1) {
            var tooHigh = lastValue * 9.5;
            var tooLow = lastValue * 0.15;
            while (value >= tooHigh)
                value /= 10;
            while (value <= tooLow)
                value *= 10;
        }
        lastValue = value;
        // process value
    }
```

Comment: Define what i right and wrong and you have most likely solved the problem.

Comment: Are you hiring, or just looking for a free answer to your homework exercise? (In all seriousness, you're going to have to put in a little effort first, then come back when you've hit a virtual wall with a)what you've got so far and b)your particular sticking point)

Comment: o anybody can write something that works. I want it to be really fast and hoping to get some inspiration from people smarter than me :)

Comment: please show some codes, let me check

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the source is

```
  IEnumerable<Double> source = ...
```

You can use Linq to check and correct decimal point:

```
  // Power we're looking for
  int power = 0; 

  var result = source.Select((v, index) => {
    Double p;

    if (index <= 0) {
      if (v == 0)
        power = 1; // <- if 0 is the first number I assume x.yz... is the answer
      else {
        p = Math.Log10(Math.Abs(v));
        power = p < 0 ? (int) (p - 0.5) : (int) (p + 0.5);
      }

      return v;
    }

    if (v == 0) // <- Nothing can be done with zero...
      return v;

    p = Math.Log10(Math.Abs(v));
    var actual = p < 0 ? (int) (p - 0.5) : (int) (p + 0.5);

    if (actual == power)
      return v;
    else
      return v * Math.Pow(10.0, power - actual);
  });
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry :) Cool code ... is it fast?

Comment: +1 because the more I look at it the more I like it haha